# Failsafe process suddenly killed on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, process, init, kill

My database service is suddenly down and I am checking on `/var/log/dmesg` to see if there is information on the process that was killed.

What is the meaning of `init: failsafe main process (761) killed by TERM signal`?

Is it a bug?

```
[   29.358667] type=1400 audit(1468163174.380:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=738 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.358671] type=1400 audit(1468163174.380:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=738 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.408134] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   29.410865] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   29.412718] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   29.546957] init: failsafe main process (761) killed by TERM signal
[   29.583799] init: Failed to obtain startpar-bridge instance: Unknown parameter: INSTANCE
```

Answer (score 4):

That is not a bug, it is a good-news message that can be safely ignored :)

`failsafe` is a process on systems that use `upstart` that detects if the system failed to boot properly and then takes appropriate action. It always starts during the boot process but is killed by `upstart` if the boot was successful.

So this doesn't help to identify your database problem :(

---

Sources: [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1091783) | [Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#failure-modes)